# Social Media Stream

Tags: jquery, plugins, stream, feed, social-media

I am creating a website and I want a Social Media Feed on my website with multiple networks like Facebook, Twitter and Instagram and with multiple accounts. So I got 2 or more Instagram accounts and 5 Twitter accounts.

Is it possible to display all of these accounts in one feed? Does someone know easy jQuery or PHP plugings to make this possible?

I already found this [Plugin](http://www.uky.edu/seeblue/Social/example_3_light.html) but I prefer a free one and I found this [PHP Library](http://storytlr.org/index.html) but I'm not that experienced with PHP, just a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

SocialFeed.js is a jQuery plugin which displays feeds from different popular social networks (including Facebook, Twitter and Instagram). The plugin is available here on [github](https://github.com/pavelk2/social-feed/), and [here you can find a demo](http://pavelk2.github.io/social-feed/).

Comment: know any other (script) versions of social-feed.js to include LinkedIn?

Answer (score 0):

I use http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/premium-jquery-plugins/jquery-social-stream-plugin/ its only 8 dollars and ive been able to use it a number of times. Highly configurable.

Answer (score 0):

Since you prefer **free plugins**, let me share some for you as per your requirement -

1. [Instamax plugin](http://demos.codehandling.com/instamax_demo/instamax_live_edit.html) for Instagram feeds
2. [Famax plugin](http://demos.codehandling.com/famax_demo_3/famax_live_edit.html) for Facebook feeds

Both are cusotmizable and better than many premium plugins out there :)